# How to create a dask time series data frame with multiple columns

Tags: dask

I'm having trouble creating a dask time series dataframe that calculates the mean per hour over multiple columns.

This is an example of my input csv file:

```
name,date_time,num
dan,2019-01-02 00:00:00,3
ben,2019-01-02 00:00:00,7
dan,2019-01-02 02:00:00,13
dan,2019-01-02 10:00:00,9
dan,2019-01-02 10:01:00,3
ben,2019-01-02 14:22:00,66
ben,2019-01-02 14:37:00,37
```

I can produce the desired output using pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot

df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
df = df.set_index(df.timestamp) # set a datetime index

df = df.groupby('name').resample('H')['num'].mean().unstack('name')

df.fillna(0).plot()
```

Desired output

```
            name    ben dan
timestamp       
2019-01-02 00:00:00 7.0 3.0
2019-01-02 01:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 02:00:00 NaN 13.0
2019-01-02 03:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 04:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 05:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 06:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 07:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 08:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 09:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 10:00:00 NaN 6.0
2019-01-02 11:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 12:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 13:00:00 NaN NaN
2019-01-02 14:00:00 51.5 NaN
```

My attempt to produce the same dataframe with dask

```py
from dask import dataframe as dd
from matplotlib import pyplot

ddf = dd.read_csv('my_file.csv')

# setting an index
ddf['timestamp'] = dd.to_datetime(ddf.date_time)
ddf = ddf.set_index(ddf.timestamp)
ddf.repartition(freq='MS')

ddf.groupby('name').resample('H')['num'].mean()
```

When I run the code above I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Column not found: resample'
```

This has me really stumped and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dask dataframe does not implement a groupby-resample operation.  It sounds like you have a feature request.  I recommend raising an issue at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new

See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/support.html#asking-for-help for requests on where to ask for help.